# C# Save Date on event, tell me how many days it has been

Tags: datetime, events, timer, save, days

So I have been working on this for quiet a while, I want to basically have something on my form2 save a datetime in Settings. Default["Day Recieved"]; on a event (button click) and I want it tell me how many days it has been on a textbox in form1. I have tried several approaches, but I cant seem to assign it properly as when I try I get a message saying that I cant convert it, even if I convert it to a datetime type, I made a whole class trying to get it to work properly, one time I had too much converting going on or something and the string passed to textbox was "TestApp.Settings+GetDate" I think that I just cant figure out how to do the right way, I have plenty of more ideas to try to get it to work, but I think there very bad ways, at least in practice, how should one do this properly without making a fool of themselves?

(I am aware I made this kinda hard to read, all I can think about is code right now and clear sentences escape my thought, since I been on this for about 8 hours, so please go easy on me, I am a nice guy :D)

Answer (score 0):

I have found out how to do it, indeed i was over complicating it and have learned my lesson,

Form2:

```
string when = System.DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(30).ToString();
            Form1.passwhen = when;
```

Back on form one, declare the global string for passwhen and then do:

```
            textBox.Text = passwhen;
        Settings.Default["Day"] = textBox10;
        Settings.Default.Save();
```

I still need to clean it up and make it load the saved setting on load, but this is simple and worked just fine, i was confused because once i save the datetime in settings, VS was saying that System.DateTime and DateTime were two different types and that i couldn't explicitly convert it.